# Multi-session CD Burning Software

Tags: linux, optical-media

Is there a **fine** and easy software for Linux that allows a user to burn files on a CD multiple times i.e. allows users to create multi-session cds.

It is better if it is in the Ubuntu repo.

Answer (score 1):

The two major burning suites on Ubuntu definitely support multi-session:

**[Brasero](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/brasero/)** is the "keep-it-simple" variant. It allows you to burn, copy and erase CD and DVD media: audio, video or data. *Brasero* supports a.o. on-the-fly burning, and offers multi-session support.

[image: Brasero]
<sup>Brasero (source: [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/brasero/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

**[K3b](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/k3b/)** is an alternative – maybe a little more complex, but also offers much more functionality. To get started, "beginners mode" makes it easier to use – while you can unleash its full powers in advanced mode.

[image: K3b]
<sup>K3b (source: [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/k3b/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

Choice is yours. Depending on the desktop variant of Ubuntu you have installed, one or both of them might be already available from the menus.

Comment: Both of these Are quite out of the box apps. K3b is Heavy with H capital and Brasero regularly fails to burn isos. But after googling a little more I found out xfburn Its installed and runs pretty smooth

Comment: @Adityaultra Be welcome to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) then :)